# find current workspace name in bazel query

Tags: bazel

I want to retrieve current workspace name using `bazel info` or `bazel query` or some other smart tool (not  `cat` + `grep`)

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any "smart" way.

What do you mean by "current" workspace? Why is `cat` + `grep` not good enough?